# prove that there is a complete language in $L \cup \{A_{TM}\}$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, complexity-classes

$A_{TM} = \{\langle M,w\rangle\mid w\in L(M)\}$

$L$ = complexity class containing decision problems that can be solved by a deterministic Turing machine using logarithmic space

Given the language $L \cup \{A_{TM}\}$,

we will say that $A$ is complete in $L \cup \{A_{TM}\}$ if:

- $A \in L\cup\{A_{TM}\}$
- For every $B\in L \cup \{A_{TM}\} \implies B\le_LA$

Is there a complete language in $L \cup \{A_{TM}\}$?

Comment: What is $L$? What is $A_{TM}$?

Comment: @dkaeae Please see my edit

Comment: Which langauge do you think would be a good candidate to be complete in this class? How would you go about proving it?

Comment: Does $A_{TM}$ reduce to any logspace language? Does it reduce it itself? Basically, the first thing that you might guess would be the answer is the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, debating between $A_{TM}$ and $L\cup \{A_{TM} \}$ as the candidates. If I choose A as $L\cup \{A_{TM} \}$ then for any $B$, if $x \in B$, $x\in L$ or $x \in A_{TM}$ therefore $x \in A$. if $x \notin B$ then $x$ is not in $A$

Comment: Observe that $L\cup \{A_{TM}\}$ is not a language, it is a class of languages.
Try using $A_{TM}$ as a candidate.

Comment: So if I use $A=A_{TM}$ as my complete language candidate. For any other language $B \in L \cup \{A_{TM}\}$, if $x \notin B \implies x \notin A_{TM} \implies x \notin A$. And if $x \in B$ if $x \in A_{TM}$ it directly means $x \in A$. Now I'm only left with the case of $x\in L$ which I'm not sure about. $x \in L \implies x \in A_{TM}$? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that $A_{TM}$ is complete for your class.

In order to show that, we need to show that for every language $A\in L\cup \{A_{TM}\}$, it holds that $A\le_L A_{TM}$.

First, if $A=A_{TM}$, then the trivial reduction suffices. That is, a reduction that given input $x$, return $x$. Clearly $x\in A_{TM}\iff x\in A_{TM}$.

Now, if $A\in L$, we need to work slightly harder. We need to show that $A\le_L A_{TM}$. In order to do that, we construct a reduction from $A$ to $A_{TM}$, as follows: let $M$ be a deterministic TM that decides $A$ in logspace (why does there exist such a machine?).

Now, the reduction works as follows: given input $x$, the reduction uses $M$ to check whether $x\in A$. If $x\in A$, the reduction outputs $\langle\epsilon, T_1\rangle$, where $T_1$ is a TM that accepts every input immediately. If $x\notin A$ the reduction outputs $\langle\epsilon, T_2\rangle$, where $T_2$ is a TM that rejects every input immediately. Note that $T_1,T_2$ are fixed, i.e. they are hard-coded in the reduction.

Try to prove that this reduction is correct, and that it is indeed in logspace.